# How to set a local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a vanity url in a callback based on a user's name with the following method:

```
before_create :generate_vanity_url

def generate_vanity_url
    vanity_url = self.name
    vanity_url.gsub!(/[^\w]/,"") 
end
```

The problem that occurs is that not only the variable vanity_url gets affected by the gsub! method, but the name attribute as well. What am I doing wrong?

Ps. the method is more extensive, but I have shortened it down for the purpose of clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge (which may be poor) this is a result of copy-on-write.
Do like that

```
vanity_url = self.name.dup
vanity_url.gsub!(/[^\w]/,"")
```

Simple example in `irb`

without `.dup`...

```
> a = "asdf"
=> "asdf"
> b = a
=> "asdf"
> b.gsub!(/a/, 'q')
=> "qsdf"
> a
=> "qsdf"
> b
=> "qsdf"
```

... and with `.dup`

```
> a = "asdf"
=> "asdf"
> b = a.dup
=> "asdf"
> b.gsub!(/a/, 'q')
=> "qsdf"
> a
=> "asdf"
> b
=> "qsdf"
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to use `.dup`, just don't use `.gsub!`

- `.gsub!` is a destructive method, meaning it modifies the original.
- `.gsub` is non-destructive and does not modify the original

So yeah, something like this should do the trick

```
before_create :generate_vanity_url

def generate_vanity_url
  @vanity_url = self.name.gsub /[^\w]/, "" 
end
```

Also `\W` is the same thing as `[^\w]` so do this instead

```
before_create :generate_vanity_url

def generate_vanity_url
  @vanity_url = self.name.gsub /\W/, "" 
end
```

---

```
~ % pry
[1] pry(main)> str = "hello world"
=> "hello world"
[2] pry(main)> str.gsub /o/, "a"
=> "hella warld"
[3] pry(main)> str
=> "hello world"
[4] pry(main)>
```

Comment: You are right, but there's no lesson learned in switching to `gsub`. COW is important Ruby feature worth knowing about.

Comment: What do you mean there's "no lesson learned"? `gsub!` should've never been used in the first place.

Comment: In this case - maybe. But @yor mazar will use it someday anyway, I think it's worth knowing what side effects it may have.